# How to pivot a dataframe to a wide format

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

Suppose I have a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'header': ['age', 'height', 'weight', 'country', 'age', 'height', 'weight', 'bank_id', 'age', 'height', 'weight', 'country'],
                     'values': ['1', '6 ft', '10 kg', 'India', '2', '5 ft', '20 kg', 'A123', '3', '5.5 ft', '30 kg', 'Japan']})

# display(data)
     header  values
0       age       1
1    height    6 ft
2    weight   10 kg
3   country   India
4       age       2
5    height    5 ft
6    weight   20 kg
7   bank_id    A123
8       age       3
9    height  5.5 ft
10   weight   30 kg
11  country   Japan
```

Now I want to transpose them using Python so that they look something like this:

[image]

There are some rows with no data, and they will remain blank.

I was trying with the code:

```
data.pivot_table(columns="header",values="values",aggfunc="max")

[out]:
header age bank_id country height weight
values   3    A123   Japan   6 ft  30 kg
```

But it is not giving the proper result. It's only showing a single row.

Answer (score 3):

- [Pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) doesn't work quite as expected, because the values in `data` have unique indices.
- In order for pivot to correctly associate the values, the groups must share an index.
- The rows can be grouped by 4, in this case, and are ordered, so we can create a new index, and correctly pivot `data`.
- This uses an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/), `:=`, and is only valid from python 3.8.

```py
import pandas as pd

# set up test dataframe
data = pd.DataFrame({'header': ['age', 'height', 'weight', 'country', 'age', 'height', 'weight', 'bank_id', 'age', 'height', 'weight', 'country'],
                     'values': ['1', '6 ft', '10 kg', 'India', '2', '5 ft', '20 kg', 'A123', '3', '5.5 ft', '30 kg', 'Japan']})

# create a unique index; replace 4 with the real group size
# the associated groups in data, must be consecutive
x = 0
data.index = [x := x+1 if i%4 == 0 else x for i, _ in enumerate(data.index)]

# see the indices are matched for each group compared to the OP
    header  values
1      age       1
1   height    6 ft
1   weight   10 kg
1  country   India
2      age       2
2   height    5 ft
2   weight   20 kg
2  bank_id    A123
3      age       3
3   height  5.5 ft
3   weight   30 kg
3  country   Japan

# create a wide dataframe
wide = data.pivot(columns='header', values='values').reset_index(drop=True)

# header is the .name of columns, to make it nothing
wide.columns.name = None
```

```
# display(wide)
age bank_id country  height weight
  1     NaN   India    6 ft  10 kg
  2    A123     NaN    5 ft  20 kg
  3     NaN   Japan  5.5 ft  30 kg
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be pivoting columns in order to get distinct columns for the new dataframe, and then eliminate NaN values for each column, and lastly combine them by using `pandas.concat` function :

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'header': ["age" , "height" ,  "weight" , "bank_id",  "country", "age" , "height" ,  "weight" , "bank_id", "country", "age" , "height" ,  "weight" ,  "country" ],
                     'values': [   "1",    "6 ft",    "10 kg",        "",    "India",   "2" ,   "5 ft" ,   "20 kg" ,    "A123",        "",   "3" , "5.5 ft" ,   "30 kg" ,    "Japan" ]})

pvt_data = data.pivot( columns='header', values='values' )
ls_col = list(pvt_data.columns)

ls_cols = []
for col in ls_col:     
    ls_cols.append(pvt_data[col].dropna().reset_index(drop=True, inplace=False))

print( pd.concat([ls_cols[0],ls_cols[1],ls_cols[2],ls_cols[3],ls_cols[4]],axis=1) )
```

```
      age bank_id country  height weight
    0   1           India    6 ft  10 kg
    1   2    A123            5 ft  20 kg
    2   3     NaN   Japan  5.5 ft  30 kg
```

Answer (score 0):

`age` seems to be the starting point of every new data point; we can use that knowledge when reshaping the data, to indicate the start of a new row for pivoting:

```py
(data
.assign(counter = data.header.eq('age').cumsum())
.pivot('counter', 'header', 'values')
.loc[:, ['age', 'height', 'weight', 'country', 'bank_id']]
.rename_axis(index = None, columns = None)
.reset_index(drop=True)
)
  age  height weight country bank_id
0   1    6 ft  10 kg   India     NaN
1   2    5 ft  20 kg     NaN    A123
2   3  5.5 ft  30 kg   Japan     NaN
```